# Setting up Payout on the Microsoft App Hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketing

I am a Windows Phone 7 developer from India. I want to set up the Payout option on the App Hub for the Paid apps I release.

What's the procedure? Do I have to physically mail the W-8 form to Microsoft? Any other things I should know about?

Can I release a paid app now and set up the payout later, in a month or so?

Comment: It seems like this is something that should be answered by the [App Hub FAQ](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to ask on the App Hub forms.

**I'm speaking from what i know about releasing xbox games.**

You can release a paid app and set up the payout later. You'll get any amount earned so far in your first payout.

Yes, physically mail the W-8 form.

For any other things to know, search the forums at http://forums.create.msdn.com/